# Where does Rails show the logging output

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2

In some method I am wrting something like this:

```
Rails.logger.debug("------I WAS HERE ------- ")
```

I can see that if I put a break point on the next line of that code, it is hitting that break point, using RubyMine IDE and running the server it from its Debug mode, so it has passed that logger.debug method but where did it print it? I can't find it in Console ... Is there an easier way?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Logs by default go to the `#{Rails.root}/log/#{Rails.env}.log` file.  Most likely that's `development.log` in your case.

Comment: now I have problem finding that path :) how about "puts" ? maybe I just write a puts , then hopefully that one shows in console

Comment: `puts` will show up in the console, yes.  Your log directory is at the top level of your project - e.g. so wherever you're looking in redmine, just go upwards from the current code until you get to the top of the project (e.g. where the `app`, `lib`, and other dirs are).

Comment: If your app isn't logging to the default path and you don't want to guess and check where the logger output is going, and you are in a console or other environment where you have access to the logger object (which you do if you can run `Rails.logger.debug`), then you can also get the path with this: `Rails.logger.instance_variable_get("@logdev").dev`. That will return the object that's receiving the logger output. If it's a file, you can additionally call `path` on that to get the full path.